# How to fire Swing GUI events for Unit Testing

Tags: java, swing, unit-testing, junit, tdd

I'm developing a swing application using TDD. My logic is nicely decoupled and triggers by listening to focus events. But I'm not able to fire those events programatically.

I thought that `field.requestFocus()` would fire focusGained() but it doesn't. I've read that it might be because there's no display.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
public class SomeClassTest extends TestCase{
    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        someLogic();
        for (JTextField field : fields[]){
            field.requestFocus();
            assertTrue(condition);
            ...
    }
```

How can I fire the FocusEvents both 'focusGained' and 'focusLost'? considering that this is for junit testing, an option without GUI would be awesome.

Edit: Using the pattern in the answer I've been able to fire all kind of GUI related events, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to trigger the method I wanted by using the `decorator pattern` to wrap my JTextFields in their own listener. Since the DecoratedJTextfield implements focusListener, the focusGained() method can be easily called on it.

Here it is an example of the decorator class,:

```
public class SmartTextField implements FocusListener{
private JTextField field;
public SmartTextField(JTextField field) {
    this.field = field;
}
@Override
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    //Here you can add logic that applies to the field, e.g.
    field.selectAll();
    ...
}
@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    ...
}
public JTextField getField() {
    return field;
}
```

Now for the testing it becomes quite easy, you can even call the method using null events! but you will likely need the source for your logic.

```
@Test
public void testSomeMethod() {
    ...
    for (SmartTextField field : SmartTextFieldCollection())
        field.focusGained(new FocusEvent(field.getField(),FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED));
        field.focusGained(null);
        assertTrue(condition);
        ...
}
```

Code bonus! For the implementation, just add the decorated field as a focus Listener, it will work nicely both when running and testing:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField();
SmartTextField smartTextField = new SmartTextField(field);
field.addFocusListener(smartTextField);
```

This was particularly helpful because I now have a self sufficient and easy to test textField. 
The decorator in implements the fields own logic, like data validation and in my case preparing information to be updated later, hope it helps. It really did for me, proud of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read that it might be because there's no display.

Correct, only a visible component on a visible GUI can receive focus. Then the FocusEvent will automatically be generated.

> an option without GUI would be awesome.

You might be able to use:

```
field.dispatchEvent(...);
```

Then you would dispatch a `focusGained` event.

Don't know if this will work or whether the `dispatchEvent()` method also has a check that the component must be visible.

Comment: Tried with `field.dispatchEvent(new FocusEvent(field, FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED));` and instantiating the Focus Event by itself `new FocusEvent(field, FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED)` but still nothing is triggered on the listener. too bad, Is there any way to mock the visibility, because even actionEvents are not triggered, I might end up implementing my own non gui event but I would rather use the built-ins in swing

Comment: `Is there any way to mock the visibility` - it may be more than just visibility. There are also methods like "isDisplayable()". I don't know what all the internal checks are for the dispatchEvent() method to work. I also don't know of any other approach to use.

Comment: Got it, just answered my own post, proud of my solution, you confirming the limitations of the method sure help out, is interesting to see the FocusGained event details when the object is not displayed, `java.awt.event.FocusEvent[FOCUS_GAINED,permanent,opposite=null] on javax.swing.JTextField`and then lists the JtextFields details, that opposite=null seems interesting